# Space between elements inside BoxPanel in scala Swing

Tags: swing, scala, layout

I'm trying to lay the components out in scala Swing using BoxPanel (which uses BoxLayout).
I want to add a space between the components. The normal way of doing that is `javax.component.Box.createVerticalStrut(...)`, but I cannot add the component created by this method call to a BoxPanel - compiler complains that `scala.swing.Component` required while `java.awt.Component` found.

As pointed out  in
http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/How-to-add-a-plain-AWT-Component-to-a-Scala-Swing-container-td2325998.html, Scala doesn't support awt components.

I haven't found any suitable subclass of `scala.swing.Component` that can be used for this purpose. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/Component.html

What is the preferred way of adding space between elements in BoxPanel?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add it on the BoxPanel's peer component like in the example below:

```
new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
    contents += new MyButton()
    peer.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(2))
    contents += new MyComponent()
}
```